# Loose coupling in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, loose-coupling

I was trying to implement loose coupling in one of my Flutter projects. It was not able to find the method.
Have replicated the same in a simple Dart code, how can I fix this, and is there some way to achieve loose coupling in Dart?

```
abstract class A{}

class B extends A{
  void help(){
    print("help");
  }
}

class C {
  A b;
  C({required this.b});
  void test(){
     b.help();
  }
 
  
}

void main() {
 var c = C(b:B());
  c.test();
  
}
```

Giving error at `b.help()`, the method does on exist.

Exact error

```
The method 'help' isn't defined for the type 'A'.
```

Comment: "Loose coupling" is not something one "implements" - it's just a guiding philosophy.

Comment: Also, _avoid inheritance_ in OOP design. Otherwise you'll get stuck in a taxonomic tarpit. Also, read this: https://boxbase.org/entries/2020/aug/3/case-against-oop/

Comment: @Dai yes correct, but i was trying to have it in my flutter proj, so that we can have an instance factory and i could provide diff instances based on need. That way I can execute diff functionality

Comment: The factory-pattern has little directly to do with concepts of loose-coupling, it's just another design-pattern.

Comment: Please pardon me, but how can we have factory patter without extending interface/abstract https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm

Comment: I am being language independent here.

Comment: That's not a good example though: you linked to OOP Design Patterns for Java, but those have limited applicability to more modern languages like Dart and Go  that feature things like implicit-interfaces and structural-typing. Anyway, you still don't need (Java-style) class inheritance to implement the factory-pattern (and its cousins), for example, in Dart you can just pass function-pointers around - which itself is far, far, far simpler than Java-style `AbstractJavaBeanFactoryFactory`-style messes.

Comment: Make sense, thanks a ton..!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b` is known to be of type `A`, and the `A` interface does not provide a `help` method.

I don't know exactly what your definition of "loose coupling" is (it'd be better to describe a specific problem that you're trying to solve), but if you want `help` to be callable on type `A`, then you must add it to the `A` interface.

You alternatively could explicitly downcast `b` to `B` with a runtime check:

```dart
class C {
  A b;
  C({required this.b});
  void test() {
    // Shadow `this.b` with a local variable so that the local
    // variable can be automatically type-promoted.
    final b = this.b;
    if (b is B) {
      b.help();
    }
  }
}
```

Or if you want duck typing, you could declare (or cast) `b` as `dynamic`:

```dart
class C {
  dynamic b;
  C({required this.b});
  void test() {
    try {
      b.help();
    } on NoSuchMethodError {}
  }
}
```

although I would consider the last form to be bad style.

Comment: Yes that would work, but it would give too many if-else, will switch back to the tight couple.

Comment: @AlpitAnand As I mentioned, it would help to know exactly what your definition of "loose coupling" is and what specific problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Well, i was intending to have an object factory, which will spit out instances of a class based on need, and then we can use it to call their respective function.

Comment: Something like this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm

Comment: @AlpitAnand When I ask for "what specific problem you're trying to solve", I mean something concrete.  *Why* do you want to use a factory pattern?   Will you have derived factories that override your factory function?  Without these details, you risk falling into the trap of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).

Comment: Not exactly a problem trying to solve, just started a new project and want to model my class according to that pattern.

Comment: @AlpitAnand And *why* that pattern?  What do you hope to achieve from it?  What scenarios do you expect to happen for which that pattern would be advantageous?  If you don't actually have an existing reason nor a foreseeable reason to use that pattern, [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).